# Sencha Touch - datepicker to display year and month only

Tags: datepicker, sencha-touch

I am working with sencha to build mobile app.

I have created one page in which there is 3-4 datepickers.
I need to display all in different formats like one datepicker in dd/MM/yyyy , other to display 
MM-yyyy and in another only year.

Please guide me how can i do this

Comment: did you find a solution for this? I need to use a date picker also but I only want it to have month and year. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Sencha Touch 2

to display the date MM-yyyy

```
var date = new Date();
  alert(Ext.Date.format(date, 'm/Y'));
```

And dd/MM/yyyy

```
var date = new Date();
  alert(Ext.Date.format(date, 'm/d/Y'));
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply , but using this i can get date in various format but i want to display 4-5 datepickers like select year then its display year only and on its click drill-down year selection only,same for Month , week etc..

Comment: I have used Ext.apply(Ext.util.Format, {defaultDateFormat: 'd-M-Y'}); but its make all datepickers in same format

Answer (score 6):

The 'slotorder' config option allows you to specifiy the order of the days, months and years - but also, you can just leave out the ones you don't want. I only wanted months and years so:

```
{
        xtype:'datepickerfield',
        picker:{xtype:'datepicker', slotOrder:["year", "month"],}
```

},

Answer (score 0):

For example you can adding:

```
"dateformat: "d.m.Y" "
```

property in each field with the "correct" date format